# Error installing MediaWiki

Tags: php, apache, mediawiki, cpanel

When I tried to install mediawiki 1.22.1 it throws a following error on mediawiki url

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Language could not be converted to string in /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Exception.php on line 722
```

But strangely if I again try to visit the same url then it shows the installed mediawiki. If I close the window and reopen it then again it shows an error. Please help.

```
Edit 1:
```

Now it throws these error messages:

```
Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Exception.php on line 750

Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Exception.php on line 750

Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Exception.php on line 750

Warning: array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given in /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Exception.php on line 750

[9fdeb921] /mw/ Exception from line 38 of /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/ScopedCallback.php: Provided callback is not valid.

Backtrace:

#0 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(325): ScopedCallback->__construct()
#1 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(871): MessageCache->load()
#2 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(791): MessageCache->getMsgFromNamespace()
#3 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/cache/MessageCache.php(729): MessageCache->getMessageFromFallbackChain()
#4 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Message.php(878): MessageCache->get()
#5 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Message.php(560): Message->fetchMessage()
#6 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Message.php(649): Message->toString()
#7 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Title.php(375): Message->text()
#8 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Wiki.php(121): Title::newMainPage()
#9 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Wiki.php(137): MediaWiki->parseTitle()
#10 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Wiki.php(530): MediaWiki->getTitle()
#11 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/includes/Wiki.php(467): MediaWiki->main()
#12 /home/hackep6t/public_html/mw/index.php(49): MediaWiki->run()
#13 {main}
```

Comment: could you post the code around line 722?

Comment: Please check what PHP version MediaWiki 1.22.1 requires and make sure you have it. Otherwise, it seems like this is a bug in their code. Also, are you installing MediaWiki through cPanel? If so, try downloading the latest code from their website, upload it to your host and manually install it.

Comment: @user1067003 this is the code snippet from line 721 to 725:  
    `if ( isset( $frame['args'] ) ) {
    $text .= '(' . implode( ', ', $frame['args'] ) . ")\n";
    } else {
    $text .= "()\n";
    }`

Comment: @EduardLuca Yes I am using cPanel. I have uploaded the code to my server but then how do I install it? I don't see any command line interface to run the commands. How do I access the command line interface?

Comment: You don't need a command line interface, as it has a web interface for installation. Just point your browser to the URL where you uploaded it and it will take you through the installation process.

Answer (score 2):

I had completely same problem. I fixed it by disabling eaccelerator in .htaccess:

```
php_flag eaccelerator.enable 0
php_flag eaccelerator.optimizer 0
```

I think it is bug in eaccelerator. If you use other optimizer, try to disable it. Because code of mediawiki seems me errorless in lines mentioned in exception backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a very, very, good reason not to, I always use the bitnami installer for mediawiki.  Among other advantages you can instantly generate the identical configuration at any time if you need it, and know it will work with other bitnami stack installers.  Also Bitnami Cloud Hosting can generate entire VMs with everything set up in a supported structure.  Just my own recommendation:

Use bitnami unless you really can't.